# Fountain generator not working

Tags: node.js, yeoman, typeerror

When trying to generate the fountain webapp I am receiving the error down below.
I've tried updating both yeoman and node, but neither has helped. Current versions are 4.5.0 for Node, 3.10.6 for npm, and 1.8.4 for yeoman. I am having this issue on both my macbook, as well as pc.

I'm new to all of this and have tried to research the answer but have not had luck finding an answer for this.

```
TypeError: this.options.ci.includes is not a function
at writing (C:\Users\Rodger\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-fountain-webapp\node_modules\generator-fountain-gulp\generators\ci\index.js:7:25)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rodger\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-fountain-webapp\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\base.js:431:23)
at C:\Users\Rodger\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-fountain-webapp\node_modules\run-async\index.js:26:25
at C:\Users\Rodger\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-fountain-webapp\node_modules\run-async\index.js:25:19
at C:\Users\Rodger\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-fountain-webapp\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\base.js:432:9
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

Comment: It seems you need to update node version. http://node.green/#Array-prototype-includes

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but as noted by @Yury, updating my node.js installation fixed the problem and it worked perfectly.  Would be nice if fountain could check version of node and give some sort of feedback for others before they run into this.